# How do i get the face and vertices after Delauny triangulation in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, 3d, delaunay

I've read the SciPy documentation here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) multiple times, and I can't seem to find an answer to this. I only see the simplices outputted.

I have this function which takes in a 3-D numpy array

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay


def get_vertices(points):
    # Convert to mesh
    tri = Delaunay(points)
    faces = points[tri.simplices]
```

How do i get the vertices? I need both the vertices and faces to create a mesh.

Comment: Are the vertices not given by `tri.points` or the input `points`?

Comment: tri.points gives all of the points but are all the points necessarily vertcies? also to load these into a mesh they are different dimensions. The points are 3-d and the simplices are 4-D.

Answer (score 0):

Since `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` is N-dimensional, the term "simplix" is a general term that refers to triangles connecting vertices in 2D and tetrahedra that connect vertices in 3D.

To create a mesh from a Delaunay triangulation, you'd have to filter out all the internal vertices and find the faces of the simplices (tetrahedra) that aren't shared by other simplices. I'm trying to work out a method for this using `scipy.spatial.Delaunay.neighbors()`. I'll update this answer if I arrive at a solution.

For anyone else that might find this answer in the meantime, [scikit-image.measure.marching_cubes()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes) is an option for creating a surface mesh (vertices and faces) from a 3D array of voxels.